# What's the difference between List<xx> and HashSet<xx> in a class constructor with EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and defining a table called ObjectiveDetail.

I've seen two ways to create the ObjectiveDetail class. One that creates
a List and the other HashSet.

What's the difference?

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail {
    public ObjectiveDetail() {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectiveDetail 
{
    public ObjectiveDetail() {
        this.SubTopics = new HashSet<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on why its important that `HashSet` enforces uniqueness in this situation, the relationships that the navigation property represents must be thought of in terms of data modeling.

While you may have `entity A` related to `entity B` more than one time, even if both relationships are 1 -> many, each relationship on the A side is related to a given instance of the entity on the B side only once.  Therefore, this is best represented with a HashSet.

In the case of the example above, `A` would have two `HashSet` navigation properties, `B1` and `B2`, rather than one List to handle both relations.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends if items on the collection should be unique or not, in terms of Database it's probably a unique constraint applied to a column.

Hashset contains only unique items, while List can contain duplicates.